# Entity Framework Best Practices with a lot of tuples

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working with asp.net core 3.1, I'm a noob so, while I'm developing my RESTFul Server I've a lot of questions about optimizations and best pratices. So, here is an example that I want to propose to you to understand if I'm doing something wrong.

First of all, this API get all patients near enough to given point ( lat, long ) with some Surname and Name search params.

```cs
IEnumerable<UserModel> patients
                          = from pat in dbManager.UserModel.AsEnumerable()
                            where pat.UserType == USER_TYPE.PATIENT
                            where EF.Functions.Like( ( pat.Surname ), "%" + Surname + "%" )
                            where EF.Functions.Like( ( pat.Name ), "%" + Name + "%" )
                            where MiscUtils.CreatePoint( user.Latitude, user.Longitude )
                                            .Distance( MiscUtils.CreatePoint( pat.Latitude, pat.Longitude ) ) 
                                                < ServerSettings.PharmacistDistanceMeters
                            select pat;
```

The first problem here is the **.AsEnumerable()**, because it load all elements in memory and so execute the Filter "client-side". I thinks this is a great preformance/memory problem right? The best way to do this is to use **IQueryable<>** , but when I execute the Distance test throw an Exception:

```
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by
 inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()
```

So, I need to the distance test and I don't want to load **ALL** the UserModel tuples. Witch is the best way to do that? I draw a solution, but I don't know if this is correct:

1. Execute a **IQueryable<>** with Surname, Name and Type filter. So now I have a subset of tuples.
2. Use the result with **.AsEnumerable()** and iterate on the Array to include only element near to a point.

In code:

```cs
IQueryable<UserModel> patients
                          = from pat in dbManager.UserModel
                            where pat.UserType == USER_TYPE.PATIENT
                            where EF.Functions.Like( ( pat.Surname ), "%" + Surname + "%" )
                            where EF.Functions.Like( ( pat.Name ), "%" + Name + "%" )
                            select pat;

var p = patients.AsEnumerable().Where( x => MiscUtils.CreatePoint( user.Latitude, user.Longitude )
                                                                    .Distance( MiscUtils.CreatePoint( x.Latitude, x.Longitude ) )
                                                                        < ServerSettings.PharmacistDistanceMeters );
```

Is this a good way to solve this problem? Or maybe there is another performace/memory friendly way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What database are you using?  Lots of database systems support geospacial indexes, Postgres for example.  Seems like you need a way to convert your CreatePoint function to something that runs in SQL.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB, but I want to extend the question more in general. Not only on geospacial type.

Comment: Yea it's a fair question.  In the end, you'd either have to pull down all the data and run client-side logic on it (C# code), or you'd have to run the logic on the database in the form of a view, sproc, computed field, function, etc.  EF can't magically translate your CreatePoint function to something that runs on any database.

Comment: Here's something I found: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mariadb-server-10-2-json-geojson-gis/

Comment: Thanks @MikeChristensen I will read this. But more answer on "generalized" question is appreciated.